# sort: cannot create temporary file in '/Data': Permission denied

Tags: makefile, permissions, temp

I've recently started working through a Tuxedo suite pipeline using a makefile written by somebody else. We've been trying to work through this particular stanza

```
reformat_read_group_tracking:
    @echo "Here we go!"
    @for file in $(FILELIST_CUFFLINKS_REFORMAT); do \
    awk '{if (NR!=1) {print}}' $(DIRPATH)/RNA_SEQ/Analysis_062216/$${file}/genes.read_group_tracking > $(DIRPATH)/RNA_SEQ/Analysis_062216/$${file}/temp.txt;\
    chmod 775 $(DIRPATH)/RNA_SEQ/Analysis_062216/$${file}/temp.txt;\
    sort -nk 3,3 $(DIRPATH)/RNA_SEQ/Analysis_062216/$${file}/temp.txt | sort -nk 2,2 | sort -nk 1,1 > $(DIRPATH)/RNA_SEQ/Analysis_062216/$${file}/temp2.txt;\
    chmod 775 $(DIRPATH)/RNA_SEQ/Analysis_062216/$${file}/temp2.txt;\
    perl formatCuffDiffOutput.pl $(DIRPATH)/RNA_SEQ/Analysis_062216/$${file}/temp2.txt > $(DIRPATH)/RNA_SEQ/Analysis_062216/$${file}/reformatted_genes.read_group_tracking;\
    chmod 775 $(DIRPATH)/RNA_SEQ/Analysis_062216/$${file}/reformatted_genes.read_group_tracking;\
    awk '{print $$1}' $(DIRPATH)/RNA_SEQ/Analysis_062216/$${file}/reformatted_genes.read_group_tracking > $(DIRPATH)/RNA_SEQ/Analysis_062216/$${file}/reformatted_genes_temp.read_group_tracking;\
    awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $$2,$$3,$$4,$$5,$$6,$$7,$$8,$$9}' $(DIRPATH)/RNA_SEQ/Analysis_062216/$${file}/reformatted_genes.read_group_tracking > $(DIRPATH)/RNA_SEQ/Analysis_062216/$${file}/reformatted_genes_temp2.read_group_tracking;\
    awk -v OFS='\t' -F '\t' '{print $$2,$$3,$$4,$$5,$$6,$$7,$$8,$$9,$$10,$$11,$$12,$$13,$$14}' $(DIRPATH)/RNA_SEQ/Analysis_062216/$${file}/gene_exp.diff > $(DIRPATH)/RNA_SEQ/Analysis_062216/$${file}/gene_exp_temp.diff;\
    chmod 775 $(DIRPATH)/RNA_SEQ/Analysis_062216/$${file}/reformatted_genes_temp.read_group_tracking;\
    chmod 775 $(DIRPATH)/RNA_SEQ/Analysis_062216/$${file}/reformatted_genes_temp2.read_group_tracking;\
    chmod 775 $(DIRPATH)/RNA_SEQ/Analysis_062216/$${file}/gene_exp_temp.diff;\
    paste $(DIRPATH)/RNA_SEQ/Analysis_062216/$${file}/reformatted_genes_temp.read_group_tracking $(DIRPATH)/RNA_SEQ/Analysis_062216/$${file}/gene_exp_temp.diff $(DIRPATH)/RNA_SEQ/Analysis_062216/$${file}/reformatted_genes_temp2.read_group_tracking > $(DIRPATH)/RNA_SEQ/Analysis_062216/$${file}/final_reformat_genes.read_group_tracking;\
    rm $(DIRPATH)/RNA_SEQ/Analysis_062216/$${file}/reformatted_genes.read_group_tracking;\
    rm $(DIRPATH)/RNA_SEQ/Analysis_062216/$${file}/reformatted_genes_temp.read_group_tracking;\
    rm $(DIRPATH)/RNA_SEQ/Analysis_062216/$${file}/reformatted_genes_temp2.read_group_tracking;\
    rm $(DIRPATH)/RNA_SEQ/Analysis_062216/$${file}/gene_exp_temp.diff;\
    rm $(DIRPATH)/RNA_SEQ/Analysis_062216/$${file}/temp2.txt;\
    rm $(DIRPATH)/RNA_SEQ/Analysis_062216/$${file}/temp.txt;\
    done ;
```

but we keep encountering an error, and the guy who wrote the code is unavailable to help right now. The issue we are having is that whenever we run the stanza it gives us the following error:

```
sort: cannot create temporary file in '/Data': Permission denied
```

None of us know exactly what is happening, but we wanted to know if this issue is a result of anything in the stanza, or if it could be a problem with the system it is running on (this makefile was written on a different machine, so the staza itself has worked before, but it is give us this error message.)

I hope this is enough to tell what the general issue is, but let me know if more information is required.

Thank you

Comment: Why is this a makefile, why not a shell script?

Comment: Make sure the directory and file names you're using do not contain any spaces, this code cannot handle that.

Comment: Apparently `$TMPDIR` is set to `/Data` and whatever is running `make` does not have permission to write there. See the `-T` option in `man sort` if this is the problem.

Comment: If I had written a makefile like that for others to use, I'd make myself scarce too.

Comment: Each output file in your recipe should be the target of a separate rule.

Answer (score 1):

With all the horrible cruft removed, this is a simple question about "what does this error message mean?" and as such not strictly acceptable on Stack Overflow.

The `sort` commands allows for you to specify a directory to use for its temporary files by setting the `TMPDIR` environment variable.  Probably some unrelated part of your code sets this variable for altogether unrelated reasons; and quite possibly, it should simply use a lowercase variable name instead, to avoid clashing with the reserved variable used by `sort` and some other utilities (upper case is reserved for system variables, but conventions from other languages sometimes lure people into believing that it's unproblematic or even recommended practice to use upper case for their private variables).

The Makefile snippet is too complex and hairy to properly refactor, but I can offer some observations;

- `sort -options | sort -different -options | sort -others -still` is probably completely useless.  The third `sort` will reorder everything so the results from the first two will be lost.  We can speculate that the intent is to use the first two for secondary keys, but the usual way to do that is to specify multiple `-k` options (and without them, there is no guarantee that the sort order of unspecified fields in the last `sort` invocation will be preserved or stable).
- `chmod`, `rm`, and most other standard file-oriented Unix utilities allow you to specify multiple file names in one go.  `rm one two` is more economical and readable than `rm one; rm two`, especially if the path names are long and repetitive (though you might want to refactor to fix them too).
- The `chmod` commands look mostly superfluous here, anyway, in particular on the files you are going to remove at the end of the recipe.  If you have trouble with permissions, maybe issue a more relaxed `umask` at the beginning of the long command.
- Obscuring the `Makefile` by putting `@` in front of targets so you can't see what they are doing is a pet peeve of mine.  Take it out so you can see what you are doing.  If `make` is too verbose for you, you can easily run it with `make -s` to keep it quiet.  There is a reason it prints what it is doing when you invoke it without the `-s` option, you know.
- Looping over files in a `Makefile` target is an antipattern.  The proper way to do this is to name the files you want to produce and tell `make` how to make each set of output files from an individual input file.
- The massive repetitiveness of the long file names here is obviously impairing legibility.  Define a constant and use that, for Pete's sake.

Completely off the cuff, here is an untested and probably broken attempt at refactoring this, mainly to give you an illustration of what I am getting at, rather than to actually produce working code out of this mess.

```
# Assuming GNU Make for the $(foreach ...) and $(patsubst ...) functions
# Not clear whether there are other output files you actually want?
resultfiles := final_reformat_genes.read_group_tracking
reformat_read_group_tracking: $(foreach d,$(resultfiles),\
        $(patsubst %,$(DIRPATH)/RNA_SEQ/Analysis_062216/%/$d,\
                    $(FILELIST_CUFFLINKS_REFORMAT)))

%/reformatted_genes.read_group_tracking: %/genes.read_group_tracking
    # A slightly more economical way to say "awk '{if (NR!=1) {print}}'"
    sed 1d  $< \
    | sort -nk1,1 \
    | perl formatCuffDiffOutput.pl >$@

%/gene_exp_temp.diff: %/gene_exp.diff
    # A slightly more economical way to say "awk -v OFS='\t' -F '\t' '{print $$2,$$3,$$4,$$5,$$6,$$7,$$8,$$9,$$10,$$11,$$12,$$13,$$14}'"
    cut -f2-14 $< >$@

%/reformatted_genes_temp.read_group_tracking: %/reformatted_genes.read_group_tracking
   awk '{print $$1}' $< >$@

%/reformatted_genes_temp2.read_group_tracking: %/reformatted_genes.read_group_tracking
    # A more economical way to say "awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $$2,$$3,$$4,$$5,$$6,$$7,$$8,$$9}'"
    cut -f2-9 $< >$@

%/final_reformat_genes.read_group_tracking: \
        %/reformatted_genes_temp.read_group_tracking \
        %/gene_exp_temp.diff \
        %/reformatted_genes_temp2.read_group_tracking 
    paste $^ >$@
```

There is a fair amount of speculation here, but you should see how it relates to your original script.  You might want to add a target `clean` to remove all the temporary files separately, though in many circumstances, `make` will flush out the files it sees are not necessary for the end result automatically.

Comment: If you replace the `paste` with an Awk script I believe you could do away with most of the temporary files here altogether, though if the files are large, that might not work.  If Bash is acceptable, a process substitution `paste <(cut one) <(awk too) <(cut three)` should work nicely.

Comment: Even without that, you could get rid of at least one temporary file simply by doing `awk '{ print $$1 }' $< | paste - $(filter-out $<,$^)` in the last one (and of course adjusting the dependencies accordingly).